# What Did Paul Atreides Do As Emperor? Who Ruled While He was Missing?

Tags: dune

In *Dune* (the original and first book), Paul Atreides is able to stop the flow of spice and force the Emperor to come to Arrakis, where Paul makes it clear he will be running things from then on.  He was Emperor, but eventually was blinded and disappeared.

What did he actually do while Emperor?  And who ruled for him after he disappeared and was presumed dead until Leto II took over?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While he ruled, It was the time of [Muad'Dib's Jihad](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Muad%27Dib%27s_Jihad). After that, the events immediately preceding his departure are described in [Dune Messiah](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Dune_Messiah).

It's his sister [Alia](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Alia_Atreides) that ruled as regent after he disappeared and was presumed dead until Leto II took over.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR, it was Irulan and Alia, with Stilgar helpling, and Fremen priests doing the actual bureaucratic ruling work.